# Interpretation of MAPE in Linear Regression model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I made a Linear Regression in Python.I computed the MAPE as follows, and got a value of 0.052:

```
mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_test, pred_test)
```

Does this mean that my mean percentage error is 0.052% or 5.2% ?

Comment: What code did you use to get that MAPE?

Comment: mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_test, pred_test)

Comment: Is that scikit-learn? If so, did you look at the documentation.. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html It says it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it means 5.2%. You can easily test this, for example if we have the prediction to be 80% of the true, then the error will be 20% and you can see you get 0.2:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
y_true = [3.3, 1.5, 2.1, 7.2]
y_pred = [0.8*i for i in y_true]

mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred)
Out[9]: 0.19999999999999996
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mean absolute percentage is 5.2%.
We can compute accuracy of the regression model from the MAPE score, using this formula:

```
Accuracy = (1-MAPE)*100
```

Here in your case MAPE value = 0.052
Therefore, your model's accuracy will be `(1-0.052)*100= 94.8%`.